# mp4 tag editing with java

Tags: java, tags, mp4, mp4parser

I want to edit tags of mp4 video file in java.
I find out mp4parser on google code but there is no enough documentation for that.
What would be the best lib for editing mp4 video tags in java.
And is there any limitation for comment tag in mp4 video??

Comment: Did you see this? http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/wiki/MPEG4MetaTags

Comment: You are invited to post on the mp4parser mailing list for help. In most cases I answer quickly. Which comment box are you talking about? iTunes' ©cmt?

Answer (score 4):

So by tags you mean things like title, artist, album etc? In this case you can try the new API available in JCodec ([org.jcodec.movtool.MetadataEditor](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditor.java)). It also has a CLI ([org.jcodec.movtool.MetadataEditorMain](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditorMain.java)).

Here's the basic usage:

```
# Changes the author of the movie
./metaedit -f -si ©ART=New\ value file.mov
```

or the same thing via the Java API:

```
MetadataEditor mediaMeta = MetadataEditor.createFrom(new
    File("file.mp4"));
Map<Integer, MetaValue> meta = mediaMeta.getItunesMeta();
meta.put(0xa9415254, MetaValue.createString("New value")); // fourcc for '©ART'
mediaMeta.save(false); // fast mode is off
```

You can find a complete documentation here: http://jcodec.org/docs/working_with_mp4_metadata.html