# How to add some text data to a video file in Java

Tags: java, file, encryption, video, file-io

I want to add some string data to a video file but I don't want the video file to get corrupted. What I want to achieve is :-
1.) Add text to a video file.
2.) Extract the text from that video file.

What I tried is :-

```
public class VideoData{

            public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create file object
    File file = new File("I:/java/MyFolder/SmallVideo.mp4");

    try
    {
      //create FileInputStream object
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);


       byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
       fin.read(fileContent);

       //create string from byte array
       String strFileContent = new String(fileContent);

       System.out.println("File content : ");
       System.out.println(strFileContent);

       File dest=new File("I://java//OtherFolder//SmallVideo.mp4");
       BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dest));
       bw.write(strFileContent + "\nThis is my Text");
       bw.flush();

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);
    }
  }
}
```

Please Help me to do the above mentioned tasks.

Comment: why don't you use metadata? you can add that as metadata and retrieve it back. please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360501/mp4-tag-editing-with-java

Answer (score 1):

An MP4 file is a container that stores properly encoded video, audio, images and subtitles. It's a binary file with standard format specification which means you cannot simply add any extra data to it. Modifying the data could corrupt the file and the decoders (simply video players) might fail to render it.

Also in your code, you read the binary data from mp4 file and converted it to String. That shouldn't be the case. A video file data must be handled in binary mode, not as text.

I didn't understand your actual goal. If you are looking to store some text in MP4 file, you could consider storing it in the meta data section of the video file. [See here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_extracting_mp4_files.htm) for an example by using a third party library.

[Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) is a technique of embedding text in images and videos. I guess that's beyond your scope.